# Delphi Dynamic method invocation

Tags: delphi, dynamic, methods, invoke

Does anyone know of a free library for Delphi 2009 and below that allows you to invoke methods dynamically?

I have started writing my own code for this but I have the feeling that it is beyond me.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "invoke methods dynamically" ? Can you give us an example.

Comment: Delphi already invokes methods dynamically. That's what the `virtual` and `dynamic` directives do.

Comment: If you mean calling/invoke methods dynamically as in by name: look at the Delphi RTTI classes. If not, please explain further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is rather vague. Besides late-binding and scripting, it can mean using  a method which name you do not know until runtime.

This falls in two categories, COM methods (using variant types) or Delphi methods being found and called using RTTI. Although RTTI has changed in the latest Delphi versions, I think that  http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorConUK98/DelphiRTTI/CB140.htm would apply to D2009

Comment: I've been interested in DWS, do you know of any documentation that shows you how to call an external method from within script? Also if its possible to bind an event to a scripted method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Invoke methods dynamically" can mean a number of different things.  Simple late-binding is built into the language in the form of methods declared as `virtual` or `dynamic`, and you probably use them all the time, particularly the `virtual` ones.

But talking about "invoking methods dynamically" generally gets into *scripting* territory, making it possible to take an object and let the end-user decide, at runtime, which method to call by using the method's name.  If you want that, you need a scripting library for Delphi.

[DWS](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/) (Delphi Web Script) works quite well, and the author claims that it supports D2009, though active development work takes place on XE.  Also, as the name implies, DWS is designed primarily with web development in mind, and so the framework for binding scripts to objects in native code-land is a lot more complicated than it probably should be.

The other major alternative is RemObjects's [PascalScript](http://www.remobjects.com/ps.aspx) library.  It supports earlier versions than D2009, and its system for object binding is a lot simpler than DWS's.  Unfortunately, it's also much slower and not well supported by the author.  But, especially for simple scripts, either one should make you able to allow users to dynamically automate stuff in your program.